# I want to show posts and all of their comments in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to show all posts of mine and my friends and also wanna show the comments on that posts
here is my controller

```
$user = Auth::user();
$friend_ids = $user->friends()->pluck('friend_id')->toArray();
$posts=PostModel::whereIn('users_id',$friend_ids)
                ->orWhere('users_id',Auth::user()->id)
                ->leftJoin('users as p_user','posts.users_id','=','p_user.id')
                ->leftJoin('post_comments','posts.id','=','post_comments.post_id')
                ->leftJoin('users as c_user','post_comments.friend_id','=','c_user.id')
                -select('posts.caption','posts.image','posts.created_at','p_user.name','p_user.user_img as user_image','posts.id','c_user.user_img as commenter_img','post_comments.comment')
                ->get();
```

but the issue is that whenever any post have more than one comments it create more than one post and show one comment on any post , hope so you understand my question if not then I return my data here is the result

```
    [{"id":5,"caption":"5thpost","image":"s1.jpg","name":"roger","user_image":"roger.jpg","commenter_img":"alex.jpg","comment":"nice one"},
{"id":5,"caption":"5thpost","image":"s1.jpg","name":"alex","user_image":"alex.jpg","commenter_img":"sufi.jpg","comment":"wow"}]
```

here you can see the id 5 is repeating I want to show all comments of id 5

Comment: use the model relations to get the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go a step further and eager load from friends

`$friends = $user->friends()->with(['posts.comments'])->get()`

and you can chain on extra functions inside the with statement if required!

Likely you would want to add a between dates for the posts function for instance like:

```
$friends = $user->friends()->with(['posts' => function($q) use ($start, $end){
    return $q->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end]);
},'posts.comments'])->get()
```

you can get the posts with `$friends->posts` and the comments with `$friends->posts->comments` and all the data you want will already be loaded and it stops N + 1 queries!

In Friends Model:

```
public function posts()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

In Post Model:

```
public function comments()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Comments::class);
}
```

Comment: To the person who suggested edits, you're right! I've added them in

Comment: how should i get image from posts table it gives me error undefined property

Answer (score 1):

Don't use joins, use [Model Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships). Then you can [eager-load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) related records like:

```
$posts = $postModel->with('comments')->where...
```

The result is that each Post Model within the Collection would have a nested attribute called 'comments', the name of the method within the Model that describes the relationship. And this 'comments' attribute would contain an Eloquent\Collection of Comment Model records.